# listen to whether a device was connected to the port or not with serial port

Tags: node.js, serial-port

i am creating a project with Arduino and Nodejs (Serial Port) which reads the pulses of an ecoder that is connected to the board, could someone tell me what I have to take into account to make my application listen to the ports so that Tell me if there is an Arduino connected or not, and if there is, I should start listening. I have done a little research and I found this code:

```
setInterval(async () => {
   let ports = await SerialPort.list();
   const scannerPort = ports.filter(
     (port: any) => port.serialNumber === "YS72404M0284"
   );
   if (scannerPort.length !== 0) {
     response = { Message: "Connected" };
   } else {
     response = { Message: "Not Connected" };
   }
   console.log(response);
}, 1000);
```

But it seems to me that it is not very practical since it is executing a function from time to time, so it occurred to me if there is something like how sockets work but to listen for connections,thanks for reading me.

Comment: Connection status of a serial port used to be provided by modem control lines. E.G. look up the signal names for a DB-9 RS-232 serial connector.  If you don't have a real (acoustic phone) modem, then you could emulate the signals (e.g. Data Terminal Ready, Data Carrier Detect). If you just have the two data lines, then the remote end needs to send a hailing message(s), and your local end has to poll its serial port to receive it.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for the answer, I'm sorry, I'm a newbie and I didn't understand your answer very well, what steps should I follow more specifically to achieve that, I'm using Windows 10.